# Dirty cutlery holder hanging over glass stove lid with drip container

Tags: equipment, stove, organization

When I cook, I use cutlery to get the food from the pan, and after using them I put it on a plate that is on the table.

But I thought I could do better, putting a frame of hooks to hang the cutlery in the vertical direction having a container underneath to contain dripping broth that runs off the used cutlery.

I searched for a long time on the internet and I didn't find anything like that.
I'm thinking of making a frame like this with aluminum alloy metal blades and solder.
But I decided to come here first and ask if anyone knows the name (if there is this silverware holder) or if they could give me clues.

I decided to draw the cutlery holder I'm trying to find positioned over the open lid of a stove (I'm not a great designer).

[image: image prototype]

Comment: Hanging something involves almost always a swinging motion. Drippings will get all over the place. I would rather stay with putting your stuff on a plate next to the stove.

Comment: Not sure about the idea -  wouldn’t hanging something from a lid pose a risk of said stove lid closing from the weight and jostling of the tools? In other words, I have never seen anything like the contraption in your sketch and either you found a business opportunity or others have dismissed the idea for a reason.

Comment: I have seen products sold as "upright spoon rest" that hold your utensils vertically, with the business end sitting in a small bowl up collect drips and the handle up so that it stays clean. This isn't the same as your idea, but seems to address your concern and the potential problems Stephie and Johannes mention

Comment: Even more than the drippings and the stove lid closing, I'm concerned about OP reaching over boiling and steaming pots to get to the tools, depending on how the stove is positioned relative to the rest of the kitchen (e.g. bench, walls)

Comment: It is quite common to have clean cutlery stored not in a drawer, but hanging from hooks, either fastened separately to a wall, or hung over a rail. If you want to hang food-dripping ladles and the like, all you would need in addition is a small vessel on the back of the stove to catch the drippings - is this equivalent to what you are looking for?

Comment: why not just put them in a pint glass?

Comment: @dandavis Thank you for the comment, but the point is that I do not want to go outside the air space above the stove, avoiding walking with dirty cutlery through the kitchen space, isolating any drop or broth (for example) to the stove and prototype that I drew and that should be supported on the stove in some part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a utensil rack with drip tray, one example here on [Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/listing/791313394/vintage-white-enamel-utensil-rack-drip).

The design seems to have phased out of fashion, all the items I can find that resemble your drawing are labeled "vintage" and have this older look to them - including construction materials (enamel instead of SS / plastic / aluminum).

I get not having enough bench space and wanting to save as much as possible, and your design in specific would work if it was **NOT attached to the stove lid**, but instead attached to a wall to the side of your stove so you don't have the following risks (pointed out in the comments by myself and others):

- Stove lid closing under the weight of the tools (@Stephie)
- You reaching out over steam / oil spatter / other hot surfaces to hang your tools (myself)
- Dripping tools going over other pans (@Johannes_B)

Comment: Exactly, the design of the utensil is very similar, moreover the model presented by you has a vertical surface preventing the utensil from dirtying the vertical wall that supports it (I forgot about this detail). But even so, I would only want to hang it over the stove to facilitate its removal for cleaning purposes with running water, sponge and this means the possibility of easily detaching it from the vertical wall that would support it. But this can be achieved by adapting with some soldering details on this model sent by you.